# Why libc++abi.dylib causing my app to crash?

Tags: ios, iphone, system

I got this crash from fabric but not able to find out the reason yet. Following are the threads that fabric reports me. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this type of crash?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4b334 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x188cf59c4 abort + 140
3  libc++abi.dylib                0x1887c11b0 __cxa_bad_cast + 130
4  libc++abi.dylib                0x1887dac04 
default_unexpected_handler() + 302
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1887e8820 _objc_terminate() + 124
6  AppName           0x100339dfc CLSTerminateHandler() + 4298694140
7  libc++abi.dylib                0x1887d75d4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x1887d71a8 __cxa_rethrow + 144
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1887e86f8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
10 CoreFoundation                 0x189c62e00 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 532
11 GraphicsServices               0x18b6cc074 GSEventRunModal + 100
12 UIKit                          0x18ff14130 UIApplicationMain + 208
13 AppName           0x100156440 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x188c7159c start + 4  

1: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d63224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d6309c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189d34e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189d32adc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189c62d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  Foundation                     0x18a77cd64 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x18a79db34 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7  UIKit                          0x19089e5f8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x18a87a2c8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4975c _pthread_body + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4966c _pthread_body + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d84 thread_start + 4  

2: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d63224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d6309c mach_msg + 72
2  AppName           0x1003277c8 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4298618824
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4975c _pthread_body + 240
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4966c _pthread_body + 282
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d84 thread_start + 4  

3 : GAIThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d63224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d6309c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189d34e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189d32adc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189c62d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  Foundation                     0x18a77cd64 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x18a7d16b4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  AppName           0x100307b24 +[GAI threadMain:] + 4298488612
8  Foundation                     0x18a87a2c8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4975c _pthread_body + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4966c _pthread_body + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d84 thread_start + 4  

4: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d63224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d6309c mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x189d34e88 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x189d32adc __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4  CoreFoundation                 0x189c62d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5  CFNetwork                      0x18a46eca4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6  Foundation                     0x18a87a2c8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4975c _pthread_body + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4966c _pthread_body + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d84 thread_start + 4

5: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e47274 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d7c start_wqthread + 4

6: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e47274 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d7c start_wqthread + 4

7: Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d78 start_wqthread + 126

8: Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d78 start_wqthread + 126

9: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e47274 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d7c start_wqthread + 4

10: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e470a0 _pthread_wqthread + 792
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d7c start_wqthread + 4

11: Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d78 start_wqthread + 126

12: GCDAsyncUdpSocket
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4bc30 _pthread_workqueue_addthreads + 72
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x188c4fcec _dispatch_global_queue_poke_slow + 76
3  AppName           0x10005d3f4 -[GCDAsyncUdpSocket notifyDidReceiveData:fromAddress:withFilterContext:] (GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m:980)
4  AppName           0x100067698 -[GCDAsyncUdpSocket doReceive] (GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m:4459)
5  AppName           0x10005f4d8 __57-[GCDAsyncUdpSocket setupSendAndReceiveSourcesForSocket4]_block_invoke260 (GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m:1760)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x188c3e9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x188c4b604 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 448
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x188c57c1c _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x188c408a0 _dispatch_source_invoke + 804
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x188c4c964 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 560
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x188c422cc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 884
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x188c4d950 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 256
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x188c54170 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 760
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e4708c _pthread_wqthread + 772
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d7c start_wqthread + 4

13: Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x188d81a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e47274 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x188e46d7c start_wqthread + 4
```

I have replaced my project name with word "AppName" in above code.
Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this question it's have same call trace, might be there is some  unhandled exception in your app  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714220/crash-on-pthread-kill

Comment: Please recheck if you have confirmed to the protocol GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate and the delegate for GCDAsyncUdpSocket instance is not nil. Because according to the code from "GCDAsyncUdpSocket" class, in `-[GCDAsyncUdpSocket notifyDidReceiveData:fromAddress:withFilterContext:]` they are directly calling `[theDelegate udpSocket:self didSendDataWithTag:tag];` without checking if the delegate is nil or not.